# Eclipse workbench translation does not show translations for SWT

Tags: internationalization, eclipse-rcp

To translate my RCP App. I would like to use fragments. I have followed this tip from [vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseInternationalization/article.html#translating-swt-and-jface-code) to translate SWT and JFace and it worked very fine.

Now I would like to translate workbench. Using the same approach, I have created a fragment project, and put properties files along with their packages extracted from related babel project: org.eclipse.ui.workbench.nl_XXXX.

- The properties files are located inside packages named equally to the ones in the host plugin
- I've added a fragment to the RCP feature project
- I've added a fragment to the launch configuration

But it doesn't work!

Does someone have any idea what I'm doing wrong and if my solution is the right approach?

Comment: What does the osgi.nl setting look like in your launch configuration?

Comment: My launch configuration prog args are : -os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch} -nl ${target.nl} -consoleLog -data @noDefault. osgi.nl is not defined.

Comment: I've seen in documentation that -nl is equivalent to -osgi.nl

Comment: here is the output of osgi console : 841 RESOLVED  org.eclipse.swt.translations_1.0.0.qualifier Master=818
846 RESOLVED    org.eclipse.jface.translations_1.0.0.qualifier Master=811
847 RESOLVED    org.eclipse.ui.workbench.translations_1.0.0.qualifier Master=829. Meaning that fragments are resolved... ????

Comment: Which translations are you missing exactly? I.e. which fragment or bundle should they come from? And what is your `-nl` setting, what is the default/OS language, and which translations are contained in the fragments?

Comment: I'm trying to add french translation only. I am using fragment from babel for workbench : org.eclipse.ui.workbench.nl_fr. My -nl setting is ${target.nl} which is french locale. It does not work for workbench (still english language) but is ok for JFace and SWT.

Comment: What is the value of the `Fragment-Host` OSGi header of your fragment(s)?

Comment: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.ui.workbench;bundle-version="3.110.0" -
 Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.swt;bundle-version="3.106.0" and Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.jface;bundle-version="3.13.0"

Comment: This is rather strange because some strings are correctly translated like Startup_Loading or HeapStatus_buttonToolTip but others are not like "Close tabs to the left/right", "Close All", "Close Others", "Minimize", "Maximize". It seems to be related to tabfolders. Where are these strings translated ? Not in org.eclipse.ui.workbench.nl ?

Comment: I'm sorry ! I was on the wrong way ! I've found that "Close tabs to the left/right", "Close All", "Close Others" etc. are all alone in org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt, not in org.eclipse.ui.workbench. So it's org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.nl which must be used. But I'm still looking for "Close", "Minimize" and "Maximize" tooltips...

Comment: Close/minimize/maximize originate from the CTabFolder of the org.eclipse.swt bundle.

Comment: I've not been able to found SWTMessages_xx.properties in any org.eclipse.swt.nl bundles. It seems SWT provides its own translation fragments, not coming directly from babel project. I've been able to download these fragments from https://www.eclipse.org/swt/language.php. Now everything is translated. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse workbench translations can be obtained from the [Babel project](https://www.eclipse.org/babel/downloads.php), including fragments for SWT.
Unfortunately, it seems that at least for the Oxygen release the SWT fragments do not (yet) contain the actual properties files with the translated messages.

However, SWT provides its own translation fragments, that can be obtained from http://eclipse.org/swt/language.php

Note that the Babel project is mainly a community effort and since Oxygen is relatively new, it might take some time for the language packs to *catch up* with the latest release.